# Are USB power banks protected from time-limited short-circuit with a huge capacitor?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, short-circuit

I would like to put a huge capacitor (>=0.1F) to provide power when my bank switches from to external power source to battery (unfortunately it cuts off output for about 2s). 
I need an undisturbed power source for my raspberry pi and a huge capacitor is the simplest solution that came to my mind. But I have no idea whether I'd destroy my bank with this kind of treatment or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no, they're not.  For what you're describing you'll need an [inrush current limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter).

Comment: Thanks for this link. But what are the rules of selecting proper NTC termistor for given circuit?